# WPF DataTemplate Binding to Content without Path - is this a bug?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem understanding the following behavior (tested in .Net 4.0)

First: The following example works as I expected: It shows a CheckBox inside a Button.

C#:

```
DataContext = new CheckBox();
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="{Binding}"/>
```

Inside an ItemsControl with a Path ("MyProperty"), it works too:

C#:

```
DataContext = new { MyList = new List<object>() { new { MyProperty = new CheckBox() } } };
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Path=MyProperty}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But inside an ItemsControl without a Path, it replaces the Button and only shows the CheckBox:

C#:

```
DataContext = new { MyList = new List<CheckBox>() { new CheckBox() } };
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Why this example doesn't work?? Is this a bug in WPF? Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: I'm no WPF expert but I can give you a pointer. Even if in your last example you only write `<Button Content="test"/>` you still only see the `CheckBox`. So I'd start looking at `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}">`.

Comment: Yes, it looks like DataTemplate is ignored for all UIElement's in the ItemsSource list. Because if I replace the CheckBox by a new class, the Button is shown. But it isn't shown if the new class inherits from UIElement. That is very strange...

Comment: Could you add two or more checkboxes to your collection. It should give you more understanding about data contexts for collections.

Comment: I can add more Checkboxes. But for every UIElement in the list the button is replaced by the element and for everything else the button is shown with the item as its content (that is, what I expected for UIElement too).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. The `DataTemplate` isn't applied to `ContentControls`. That's why your sample code doesn't work when the `DataContext` of an item in the `ItemsControl` is a `CheckBox` but it does work when the `DataContext` is an `object`.

You are not supposed to define user interface elements in the `DataContext`/view model.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider the described behavior as WPF/XAML-bug.
ItemsControl (compared to ListView or ListBox) has no default ItemContainer (as ListViewItem or ListboxItem). With ListBox or ListView your example will work.

If you have a `List<Textbox>` as `ItemsSource`, then `ItemsControl` uses items from `ItemsSource` as ItemContainers so TextBoxes will be ItemContainers and you become
`System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='CheckBox'`
in your debug output so you DataTemplate will be ignored(without specifying ItemTemplate you will have the same issue).

To solve it you could derive from `ItemsControl` and override [IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.isitemitsowncontaineroverride(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> Determines if the specified item is (or is eligible to be) its own
>   container

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers!

I didn't know the method IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride. If I override it and always return true then all works as I have expected.

I know, that this way of implementation is not the best one. But now I understand the behavior and I'm happy ;)